# Python .split IndexError

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, date, python-2.x

New to Python. Trying to call .split to seperate time values so I can count all the login dates for april: here is what the data looks like if I call response['data]

```
[{u'email': u'wilderman.nyree@heidenreich.com'}, {u'login_date': u'2014-05-04T04:09:29-07:00', u'email': u'vrippin@gmail.com'}, {u'login_date': u'2014-04-13T20:37:31-04:00', u'email': u'eileen.gusikowski@oreilly.info'}, {u'login_date': u'2014-05-11T15:34:17-04:00', u'email': u'cstehr@keebler.com'}, {u'login_date': u'2014-04-13T17:12:20-04:00', u'email': u'onolan@gmail.com'}, {u'login_date': u'2014-04-01T02:22:55+05:00', u'email': u'ygoyette@yahoo.com'}, {u'login_date': u'2014-04-22T21:04:03+04:00', u'email': u'vblanda@gmail.com'}, {u'login_date': u'2014-05-08T22:30:57-04:00', u'email': u' ybartoletti@littel.biz'}, {u'login_date': u'2014-04-25T13:27:48-08:00', u'email': u'woodie.crooks@kozey.com'}, {u'login_date': u'2014-04-14T02:18:48-07:00', u'email': u'emilia16@block.com'}, {u'login_date': u'2014-04-20T11:02:21-10:00', u'email': u'bahringer.karl@yahoo.com'}, {u'login_date': u'2014-04-27T11:08:50+10:00', u'email': u'morissette.lalla@kuhicmuller.com'}]
```

And so on and so forth...when I run this code:

```
 loggedList = [user['login_date'] for user in response['data']]
 for login in loggedList:
    if login is not None:
     aprilList.append('-' + login.split('-')[0])


 # print aprilList
 print response['data']
```

I get this printout in the console:

```
u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014', u'-2014']
```

But when I try and access the second part of the .split list by changing    `login.split('-')[0])`to `login.split('-')[1])` I get an IndexError list is out of range.

How do I access the month part of the login dates? I think I'm close and it's hiding somewhere with the .split method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look through your output for `login.split('-')[0])`, you'll notice that one is `u'-',`

This likely means that one of your data entries has an empty login date, and so login.split is giving an array with just the empty string in it. This has 1 element, so the second index is out of bounds

Either ensure all your data is of the correct format and complete, or only try to print the month if the result of login.split is long enough

Comment: ok gotcha i see it, is there a quick way to normalize through the data to knock those out?

Comment: @AdamWeitzman you can just check for the length before accessing the element. if len(login.split('-')) == 2, or something like that.

Comment: @shravster Probably >=2.

Answer (score 2):

Use the dateutil module to do this.

```
from dateutil import parser
d = parser.parse("2014-04-13T20:37:31-04:00")
print d.month
```

Comment: Nice!, but I'm getting a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' error when I try and pass in the date as a variable

Comment: O my fault, i think this has to do with one of the logins being blank

Answer (score 2):

Add verification if `login_date` is in there for each element in the response, i would also recommend to parse your `date` into `datetime.datetime` format, so you could access all time parameters:

```
import dateutil.parser as dp

for user in response['data']:
    if user['login_date']:
        print dp.parse((user['login_date'])).month
```